# TNY268 switch when connecting HV then stop switching, not sure of EN/UV correct operation

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, pmic

I am trying to design a simple power supply using TNY268, I connected the circuit as follows:

[image]

Where the input of the attached schematic is connected to the output of a bridge and smoothing capacitor, I understood from the datasheet that at the beginning of each cycle the EN/UV pin is sampled to see if it's pulled down, then the next cycle is disabled other wise it's enabled. I ignored the feedback optocoupler and left the pin floating (not pulled down) so that the duty cycle is always maximum. Switching is not happening except when I connect the HV source then the switching stops.

So why is switching stopping? What I am missing or misunderstanding from the datasheet? Is it necessary to use optocoupler? Can I fix the duty cycle to always maximum and always switching on for testing/Educational purpose at the beginning?

Comment: "ENABLE/UNDERVOLTAGE (EN/UV) Pin:
This pin has dual functions: enable input and line undervoltage 
sense. During normal operation, switching of the power 
MOSFET is controlled by this pin. MOSFET switching is 
terminated when a current greater than 240 µA is drawn from 
this pin. This pin also senses line undervoltage conditions 
through an external resistor connected to the DC line voltage. 
If there is no external resistor connected to this pin, 
TinySwitch-II detects its absence and disables the line 
undervoltage function." From the data sheet, read the last sentence.

Comment: What voltage are you applying?

Comment: @TimWilliams 300 VDC measured after smoothing capacitor

Comment: @ronsimpson Last sentence : " If there is no external resistor connected to this pin, TinySwitch-II detects its absence and disables the line under voltage function." , Would you please elaborate more about the under voltage function and how switching is effected by disabling this functionality ?..... Yes I should be disabled as i didn't connect this resistor